# How to display an "Out of Page" (PopUp) ad from Google DFP on a Drupal 6 site?

Tags: 6, javascript, blocks, advertising

Been beating my head on this for a while now. We've recently set up Google DFP for small publishers to use with a Drupal 6 site. We use the google admanager module to display the ads properly throughout the site using blocks.

I'm trying to create an out-of-page (ie. popup) for the front page.

In the past with OpenX I accomplished this by putting popup code in a block on the page. But this hasn't seemed to work yet with DFP.

Admittedly I'm still learning the in's and out's of the system, but have tried a few different ways now to no effect.

I've tried this: https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3370474?hl=en but haven't gotten it working yet, and not sure it will even be suitable for general use by staff who submit ads.

Would love to hear how others are making this work.

Comment: Please check my edit of this question, and your answer to it. I mostly move the answer part of your question to ... your answer. And I fixed the formatting of the code you were showing (it was not shown ...). Feel free to refine / edit / etc, if you don't like my edits at all just perform a rollback, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I solved it. Below is how ...

Finally got the process of creating a pop up on DFP figured out, now onto the Drupal part of it. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/dfp/inventory-management/dfp-small-business/e4vUwjgd4lk

**UPDATE**:

Got it working this way...

OK. Looks I mostly have it.

Just bypassed the Google Admanager module and generated a tag from the ad unit page. Then I put it in my theme `page.tpl.php` header enclosed in this (to make sure it is only front page):

```
<?php if ($is_front) { ?>
<script>......</script>
<?php } ?>
```

And then put the rest in the block with php enabled. I also made sure to remove the adslot generated other than the popup.

Hackish but it does the trick.

But if anyone knows how to make it work with Google Admanager, would love to look at it.